# Use flask-migrate with declarative base instead of db.model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I want to add columns to a table in my database dynamically since I don't want to have to specify all columns when I set it up in the class

I have downloaded flask migrate which I have gotten to work with db.model but I would like to get it to work with declarative base directly.
How do I do this?

This is how I set it up using db.model

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = "static", template_folder = "templates/vue_template")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost:5432/testdb"

db =SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(80))
    username=db.Column(db.String(80))




migrate = Migrate(app,db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I then run the following commands in terminal

```
python test.py db init

python test.py db migrate -m "Initial migration."

python test.py db upgrade
```

If I then add a new column `email = db.Column(db.String(120))` to the Person table and run

```
python test.py db migrate -m "Add column"

python test.py db upgrade
```

I can then see the new column in the Person table in the database. Great.

**Question**
But how can I do the same column adding procedure with a table based on declarative_base (like below)
I.e adding a column `email = Column(String)` to the below table using flask-migrate

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=Column(String)
    username=Column(String)
```

What do I need to change to the code to make that work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-Migrate is an extension that works alongside Flask-SQLAlchemy. If you don't use Flask-SQLAlchemy then you cannot use Flask-Migrate.

But Flask-Migrate uses Alembic under the hood, and Alembic can also be used directly. So that is my recommendation, just use Alembic. It requires a bit more work in terms of configuration and setup, but it will work with your SQLAlchemy project.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies it. I have hade problems on setting up Alembic but I will post a separate question on that.